# Command Demo project for Outlook 2016 doesn't work in OWA Outlook on iphone

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-app

I'm currently developing an Outlook Add-In and so far everything works fine. It works in Outlook 2016 on PC and Outlook OWA on PC. But it doesn't work in OWA Outlook on iphone. But ND|Mail application is showing up in OWA Outlook app. My question is how to make the project working for iphone.

the demo project in here:
https://github.com/jasonjoh/command-demo

It is a great application. so cool.

Comment: Maybe you should post in the github repository issues

Comment: I believe this is because I didn't include a `<PhoneSettings>` element in the manifest for the `ItemRead` or `ItemEdit` forms. Mobile OWA doesn't support add-in commands yet, so it falls back on the settings in the `<FormSettings>` element. When I get some free time I'll try this out and update.

Comment: Hi Jason, I made it to work just by adding <PhoneSettings> and <TabletSetting>. Thank you so much. I can't stopping praise how cool is the sample app.